# Problem in accessing the values inside of the ARRAY

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im prety new in javascript, im facing a strange problem in accessing the items into an Array that are stored inside and javascript object.

Code

```
var Exp = {"no":Array(), "dateFrom":Array()}
readData();
function readData() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', sheet, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            const feeds = response.feed.entry;
            feeds.forEach(function (post) {
                Exp["no"].push(post.gsx$no.$t);
                Exp["dateFrom"].push(post.gsx$from.$t);
            });
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
};
var lengthNo = Object.keys(Exp.no).length;
var valueZero = Exp.no[0];
console.log(lengthNo, valueZero, Exp);
```

Console result

```
0 undefined 
{no: Array(0), dateFrom: Array(0)}
no: (4) ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
dateFrom: (4) ["02/2001", "07/2006", "11/2008", "03/2014"]
__proto__: Object
```

When i run this in console everything works like charm, any ideay why this is not working into script file .

Comment: Where did you populate both arrays? Its not seen in your code

Comment: Thnx for reply, the array are populated through Google Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this code:

```
var lengthNo = Object.keys(Exp.no).length;
var valueZero = Exp.no[0];
console.log(lengthNo, valueZero, Exp);
```

inside the `xhr.onload` function:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        const feeds = response.feed.entry;
        feeds.forEach(function (post) {
            Exp["no"].push(post.gsx$no.$t);
            Exp["dateFrom"].push(post.gsx$from.$t);
        });
        var lengthNo = Object.keys(Exp.no).length;
        var valueZero = Exp.no[0];
        console.log(lengthNo, valueZero, Exp);
    }
}
```

Because of the `asynchronous` nature of `xhr`

Comment: I have another dump question, can i access those two arrays outside of readData() function?

Comment: You declared `Exp` outside the function so they should be accessible as `Expo["no"]` etc

Comment: i have already declared in the begin of script outside of function. In console everything is OK, but in script both arrays seem to be zero.

Comment: *In console everything is OK, but in script both arrays seem to be zero* can you explain?

Comment: if i try something like '''Exp["no"][2]''' it return undefined, instead if i run this in console it returns 2. I think something is running before my function is called to populate the arrays. I will check internet for this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can access your object . The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property. since your object have an `arrays` as value agains `key no` , you can directly get by `Exp.no`.

```js
var Exp = {"no":["1", "2", "3", "4"], "dateFrom":["02/2001", "07/2006", "11/2008", "03/2014"]}
var lengthNo = Exp.no.length;
var valueZero = Exp.no[0];
console.log(lengthNo, valueZero, Exp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple approach. If you want create JavaScript object can use this way

```
const Exp = {no: [], dateFrom: []};
const noLength = Exp['no'].length | Exp.no.length;
const valueZero = Exp['no'][0] | Exp.no[0]; // Return 0
```